# Serie $x^{u_n}$ with $u_n \underset{ n \to +\infty}{\sim} a n^{\mu}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$a>0 \\
\mu \geq 1\\
x \in ]0,1[ \\
u_n \sim a{n^{\mu}} \\$

Could you help me prove :

1. the serie $x^{u_n}$ converges (by comparison)
2. (a) $\forall t \in ]0,1[$ and  $ m > 0$ , show that $(1-t)t^m < \frac{1}{m}$ 
   (b) deduce from (a) that for $\mu >1$ the serie converges
3. (a) for $\mu >1$, show that  $(1-x) \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} x^{u_n} \underset{x \to 1^{-}}{\to}0$ 
   (b) the previous result is false if $\mu=1$

Hint for 3 (a) : for a well chosen $\delta$ find an upper bound of $(1-x)^{\delta}$ that does not depend of $x$.

Thanks

---

My attempt :

1. $an^{\mu} > an$ because $\mu >1$ 
   so $x^{an^{\mu}} < x^{an}$ because $x \in ]0,1[$ 
   so the serie $an^{\mu}$ converges 
   $x^{u_n} = x ^ { an^{\mu} +o( an^{\mu} )} =  x ^ { an^{\mu} } x ^ {o( an^{\mu} )} \leq x ^ { an^{\mu} } \times 1 $ 
   so $x^{u_n} \leq  x ^ { an^{\mu} } $ 
   so the serie $x^{u_n}$ converges.

2. (a) Let $\phi(t)= (1-t) t^m$ for $t \in ]0,1[$. $\phi$ admits a maximum on $t^{\star}=\frac{m}{m+1}$ 
   $\phi( t^{\star})= \frac{1}{m+1} (t^{\star})^m \leq \frac{1}{m+1} < \frac{1}{m}$

Answer (score 0):

The result is not true.

For $x = \frac{1}{2}$, $\mu=1$ and $a = \frac{1}{2}$, you have
$$x^{u_n} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}$$

which tends to $1$, so it is not the general term of a convergent series.

Comment: Hi, you're right, I made an error. The correct version is $u_n \sim a{n^{\mu}}$. So with $\mu=1$ and $a= \frac{1}{2}$, the example becomes $u_n=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{n}$